# DynamoDB: Query Incorrect operand type

Tags: javascript, amazon-dynamodb

I'm attempting to read all values in a DynamoDB table above a certain value. I have the primary partition key set to a Number called Project_ID.
I am running a query to see all values above a certain ID - mostly to test out functionality, however I am getting an error when running the code.

The code:

```
    var params = {
    TableName : document.getElementById("tableName").value,
    KeyConditionExpression: "Project_ID > :v1",
     "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
        ":v1": {"N": "0"}
     }
};

docClient.query(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        document.getElementById('textarea').innerHTML += "Unable to query. Error: " + "\n" + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2);
    } else {
        data.Items.forEach(function(project) {
            //JSON.stringify(project);
            document.getElementById('textarea').innerHTML += "\n" + project.Project_Name + ": " + project.Project_Ref;
        });

    }
});
```

The output

```
    `Unable to query. Error: {
  "message": "Invalid KeyConditionExpression: Incorrect operand type for operator or function; operator or function: >, operand type: M",
  "code": "ValidationException",
  "time": "2017-04-28T10:52:31.381Z",`
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Actually, you have two errors here:

- The first one is, indeed, that you are trying to apply an operator that is not `=` on your Primary partition key. **HOWEVER, this is not the reason for the error message you get here!**
- In your error message, the `M` type is for `Mapping` (or `Dictionary`), on which the operator `>` cannot be applied. Indeed, it seams you are using the `DocumentClient` abstraction of the SDK, and as specified in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html):

> The document client simplifies working with items in Amazon DynamoDB by abstracting away the notion of attribute values.

It means that when making calls using the document client, you should be having the following query parameters:

```
var params = {
    TableName : document.getElementById("tableName").value,
    KeyConditionExpression: "Project_ID = :v1", //I modified this to fix the first point
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":v1": 0 //Not a dictionary!
     }
};
```

instead of:

```
var params = {
    TableName : document.getElementById("tableName").value,
    KeyConditionExpression: "Project_ID = :v1", //I modified this to fix the first point
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":v1": {"N": "0"} //This is an attribute value !
     }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

In KeyConditionExpression of Query API, the partition key can have only **equality operator**. The sort key can have multiple operators.

> The condition must perform an equality test on a single partition key
>   value. The condition can also perform one of several comparison tests
>   on a single sort key value.

**Example (sort key):-**

> sortKeyName < :sortkeyval - true if the sort key value is less than
>   :sortkeyval.
>
> sortKeyName <= :sortkeyval - true if the sort key value is less than
>   or equal to :sortkeyval.

You may need to use **Scan (with FilterExpression)** or **BatchGetItem** API if you wanted to get multiple items based on some criteria.

**Note:-**

Scan API will scan the whole table which is costly and inefficient.

Comment: can you provide a link?

Answer (score 0):

### `Project_ID` is the HASH key?

#### Yes

Then you would need to always perform an equality test against that attribute. That's just how DyanmoDB works. HASH keys, are always queried using an `=` test. You can then use an `and <extra condition using a sort key>` and that extra condition might use `<`, BETWEEN, `begins_with`, etc.

So your `KeyConditionExpression` can only start with `Project_ID` **=** `:v1"` and then you might add one other condition - if your table is setup using a sort key.

Dont have a sort key? Then you have a schema that only allows lookups based on `Project_ID`

### Not Sure What My Table Schema Is

> How would I know if 'Project_ID' is my HASH key?

Check My Table Description

```js
(async ()=>{
  const TableName = document.getElementById("tableName").value
  const myAWScredentialInfo = getMyCredentialsForAWS()
  const dyn = new DynamoDB(myAWScredentialInfo)
  console.log(await dyn.describeTable({TableName}).promise())
})()

// 1. the log output will contain a key called 'KeySchema'
// 2. Inside 'KeySchema' look for the entry with a KeyType:'HASH' 
// 3  Make sure the `AttributeName` of that one is 'Project_Id'
```

@ApiReference: [DynamoDB API - Query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html#DDB-Query-request-KeyConditionExpression)

@ApiReference: [DynamoDB API - Describe Table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeTable.html)