# How to do a basic sort in DynamoDb?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, nosql

Dynamodb can make the simplest of database operations difficult. I have the following table and all I want to do is simply sort by the due column. How is this achieved in DynamoDb? I read everything I could find online and there doesn't seem to be a straightforward walk through anywhere.

```
payor    |  amount  |  due  | paid
----------------------------------
Ally     |  200.00  |   13  |    1
Chase    |   80.00  |    2  |    0
Wells    |   30.00  |   17  |    1
Directv  |  150.00  |    5  |    0
```

So without considering the payor, amount or paid columns, how can I simply sort on the due column.

Comment: Are you doing a **query** or a **scan**? See also: [Is it possible to ORDER results with query or scan in DynamoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9297326/174777) and [Dynamodb scan in sorted order](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21794945/174777)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply, this can't be achieved in DynamoDB if the `due` attribute is not defined as sort key. Even if you define the `due` attribute as sort key, the ordering can be done only within the particular partition key. The ordering can't be done across the partition key.

Assume, you have defined the `due` as sort key of the table. You can use `ScanIndexForward` to `true/false` to order the items in ascending / descending order.

Answer (score 2):

Data modeling in dynamo db involves designing the partition key and then determining the sort key for a use case. Partition key is compulsory for any query. This is a basic design premise of a key value nosql store which is completely different than a relational store

Comment: Also a great explanation. Thank you.