# How to order the dynamodb query result by a property of the items?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

So I need to order the query result by the timestamps on items, and I saw that I can use `ScanIndexForward`, but how can I say that it needs to compare the timestamps?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to ORDER results with query or scan in DynamoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9297326/is-it-possible-to-order-results-with-query-or-scan-in-dynamodb)

Answer (score 1):

DynamoDB uses primary keys to uniquely identify items in the database.  A primary key is made up of a **Partition Key** and an **optional** **Sort Key**. The Sort Key is what allows DynamoDB to sort your data.

For illustration purposes, imagine you wanted to model an email inbox that allows the user to sort their email by date received.  Your table could look like this:

[image]

I'm using the users email address as the Partition Key(PK) and a timestamp (date received) as the Sort Key (SK).  Together, the PK and SK make up the unique Primary Key that represents a single email to the user.

When you perform a query to get a users emails, DynamoDB will use the Sort Key to sort the results.  By default, results will be in ascending order (`ScanIndexForward=true`)  If you want descending order, you'd use `ScanIndexForward=false`.