# Get data based on sort index AWS dynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index

I have a DynamoDB table like this:[image]

I want to list all posts irrespective of users, i-e by getting all data whose sort key is "post". How can I achieve this?

I have heard about Global Secondary Index, but couldn't figure out how to use them.

Comment: Maybe this will help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9297326/is-it-possible-to-order-results-with-query-or-scan-in-dynamodb/36883510#36883510

Comment: We cannot query without specifying partition key (PK in this case). Here's the error on executing the code:`{
  "message": "Query condition missed key schema element: PK",
  "code": "ValidationException",
  "time": "2021-10-14T07:06:39.851Z",
  "statusCode": 400,
  "retryable": false,

}`

Comment: I see. It's been long time since I worked on dynamodb. But as I recall data is partitioned by PK. So you might need to have another table where you partition by the sort key.

Comment: Yeah, I have to use GSI for this. But couldn't figure out how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create a global secondary index with a Key Schema like this:

- Partition Key: SK attribute of the base table
- Sort Key: PK attribute of the base table

It's called an **inverted index**. Then you can `Query` the Global Secondary Index by specifying the `IndexName` in the Query and search for all items that have `"post"` as the value for `SK`.

Comment: Thank you so much! It's exactly what I needed.